# What does the SmartGit conflict resolver actually mean?

Tags: git, merge, rebase, smartgit, git-merge-conflict

[image: Here is an expample of the dialoge box i am talking about]

So yeah, I am starting to get the hang of git and have been using SmartGit as the client. So far I am still learning a lot of the git language, but I know enough to understand the difference between merge and rebase for example.

Right now I'm in the middle of rebasing my branch on top of develop, but a conflict happens.

Knowing just enough means I find the text here to be a bit ambiguous, and I don't feel confident that I could solve the mess if I went ahead and experimented, so that is why I am asking for help.

I want too have their file replace the version that I have in my branch, I want to complexly discard any changes made be me *on that specific file*.
What do I select??

Thanks in advance ;)
PS: I have done some research on the topic, and there is a lot of great answers using the command line to resolve this kind of situation. I am not looking for those solutions (Unless, of course, that is the ONLY way to achieve what i want).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Smartgit, once you see the conflict, right click and open conflict-solver. If you want to overwrite changes with yours, choose ours and save. Then choose commit and it will ask for rebase and commit.

Conflict-solver shows diffs with colors and is easy to use.

Comment: Thank you for an unambiguous answer :) 

The problem with the conflict solver is that I am merging Unity files....while not being binary, they are not very git friendly when in a conflict due to reasons. That is why just plain override works better if you know whos changes you want to keep :P